# IN or LIKE ANY or?

Tags: teradata

in terms of performance, whats the best choice in this case?

```
select *
from db.table
where username in ('john', 'kevin');
```

Or

```
select *
from db.table
where username like any ('john', 'kevin');
```

Or maybe there is a best way for performance to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: I beg to differ with Dieter. I started using "like any", because it allows me to use wildcards when needed, and have seen no difference in performance.

Comment: In certain scenarios the optimizer's re-write of the IN operator to a psuedo-table/spool file may outperform the use of LIKE ANY which I do not recall as being suitable for a similar re-write enhancement.

Comment: @access_granted whenever I look at someone else's query and see "like any" used to check for equality I immediately wonder if they forgot a wild card.  It might seem reasonable to you but anyone else is going to wonder if your script is really doing what was intended.

Answer (score 2):

Of course `IN`.

Additionaly LIKE might not return the same result as the comparison rules differ, LIKE doesn't ignore trailing spaces, e.g.

```
'john' = 'john '    -- results in TRUE
'john' like 'john ' -- results in FALSE
```